# Aurelia repeat.for calling function multiple times

Tags: function, for-loop, aurelia

In an attempt to discover some performance issues we are running into with Aurelia on IE 11, I tried to just log a timer in order to track progress made. While doing so, I noticed odd behavior during a `repeat.for` iteration.

```
<div repeat.for="i of 100">
    <div if.bind="lastElement(item, $last)">${$index}</div>
</div>
```

with the function and scope

```
var count = 0;

lastElement(item, last){
    count++;
    if(last === true){
        console.log('Last Item: ' + JSON.stringify(item));
        console.log(count);
    };
    return true;
};
```

...and with the following result:

```
Last Item: 99
100
Last Item: 99
169
```

To me the result should have been:

```
Last Item: 99
100
```

For some reason there is multiple iterations or checking on this function. Can somebody explain to me what is going on here?

**UPDATE:** I was able to find a external file by jdanyho and create a [Gist](https://gist.run/?id=6137ff2c1945b82725a61575f91df295) to demonstrate. However, now I'm getting 150 instead of 169. Hmmmm...

Comment: Ooh, you're right. There are 50 extra calls, I'm deleting my answer.

Comment: I've tried the same example in local (`"GET /jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-framework@1.0.8.js HTTP/1.1" 200`) and works as expected. This could help: https://github.com/gist-run/gist-run/issues/22

Comment: We are running local with 1.0.8 as well and I updated the Gist to jdanyho's source files and same results.

Answer (score 0):

The function lastElement its call more times that the number of itens, because you do a bind with function, and in this case aurelia binding system do a dirty checking (has a timer to call the function to see if the value has changed).
To avoid dirty checking you can using the decorator @computedFrom.

In this case for using decorator i think that you cannot performing your function logic based in parameter last, must be doing based in properties.

There are many blog about this topic, but you can read the official post: 
http://blog.aurelia.io/2015/04/03/aurelia-adaptive-binding/